# QuadTree treeNode design question

Tags: xna, game-design, monogame, oop

I'm a programming newbie.

I have a Quadtree. I created a TreeNode class that the Quadtree will use as nodes. I have spriteNode that inherits from TreeNode.

However, I also have several sprite types inheriting from a Sprite class that I use to instantiate specific sprites.

When I am creating spriteNodes for example I have to cast each specific sprite type to it's parent Sprite class. When I put spriteNode into the quadtree I have to cast the spriteNode to be of type TreeNode so I can generalize the quadtree as much as possible to take different types of data.

I'm not sure if this is a great way of storing all your sprite / map data inside a quadtree, because setting it up requires a lot of explicit casts (even though cast up a level are safe).

Is my OO design approach to storing sprite / map data inside the quadtree the correct way to handle a large quadtree of data? Or is there a better, more standard way of doing things?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really an expert in quadtrees, I only coded one in my life, so I may be wrong.

However, to do what you say, you could use an Interface like IWorldObject and assign it to every object you want to insert into the quadtree. This way you just need to keep a list of IWorldObject and need no casting (assuming you implement all the needed methods in the interface).

However, if every sprite class has unique methods that you need when taking out data off the quadtree, you will still need to cast to the appropriate type.

Comment: You're welcome! Did it do the job? Do you have any other questions regarding that? :)